# Pandas: plot top to bottom performers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have some data showing how many pies each person baked (on average). I would like to plot a chart showing:

> average number of pies baked by top 10%, top 20%, ... top 100%:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

baked_count = np.random.normal(10, scale = 3.0, size = 100)

df = pd.DataFrame(baked_count, columns = ['performance'])

df['performance'].hist()
plt.show()

points_x = []
points_y = []

x = 0
for index, row in df.sort_values('performance', ascending = False).iterrows():
    y = df[df['performance'] >= row['performance']]['performance'].mean()

    x += 1

    points_x.append(x)
    points_y.append(y)

points_x = np.array(points_x)    
points_y = np.array(points_y)    

plt.scatter(points_x, points_y)

plt.axvline(points_x.min(), color='g', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1)
plt.axvline(points_x.max(), color='g', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1)
plt.axhline(points_y.min(), color='g', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1)
plt.axhline(points_y.max(), color='g', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1)

plt.show()
```

Is there some standard numpy/pyplot/pandas way to do the thing?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to calculate a cumulative mean of the sorted `performance` Series. You can do this by dividing series `cumsum()` by cumulative count. Example:

```
x = np.arange(1, df.shape[0]+1)
y = df.performance.sort_values(ascending=False).cumsum() / x
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

or a bit more elegantly with [`expanding`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.expanding.html) mean:

```
y = df.performance.sort_values(ascending=False).expanding().mean()
```